# Binary "OR" operation on a SQL column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that returns weekdays

```
Select PERSON_NAME, PERSON_DAY from PERSON_DAYS WHERE PERSON_ID = @myId
```

say I obtain

```
John 1 (mo)
John 3 (mo tu)
John 8 (th)
```

I need to obtain for John all the days when is busy. How do I a logical OR on the PERSON_DAY column in this query?

the result should be 11 (mo tu th)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well here my best so far

```
;with PowersOf2
as
(
    select 1 as Number
    union all
    select A.Number * 2 from PowersOf2 as A where A.Number < 64
)
select P.PERSON_NAME, sum(distinct P.PERSON_DAY & PowersOf2.Number)
from PERSON_DAYS as P
    left outer join PowersOf2 on PowersOf2.Number <= P.PERSON_DAY
where P.PERSON_ID = @myId
group by P.PERSON_NAME
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e3bd/5)

Comment: bitwise OR in T-SQL is `expression | expression`... why your code is so complicated?

Comment: because what you need it not just bitwise `or`, but **aggregate** bitwise `or`. you see, string concatenation is just `+`, but aggregate string concatenation...

Comment: You use "1 as P" and also "Person_Days as P"... and what CTE stands for?

Comment: well, ok, may be I was not ver accurate, let me change aliases. CTE stands for Common Table Expression

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can use a combination of [bitwise operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx) `and` and aggregate function `sum` to do what you want.

Example:

```
with person_days as (
      select 'John' as person_name, 1 as weekday --mo
union select 'John',  3  -- mo, tu
union select 'John',  8  -- th
union select 'Jane',  1  -- mo
union select 'Jane',  9  -- mo, th
union select 'Jane', 40  -- th, sa
),
Bits AS ( 
          SELECT   1 AS BitMask --mo
UNION ALL SELECT   2            --tu
UNION ALL SELECT   4            --we
UNION ALL SELECT   8            --th
UNION ALL SELECT  16            --fr
UNION ALL SELECT  32            --sa
UNION ALL SELECT  64            --su
UNION ALL SELECT 128
)
, person_single_days as (
select distinct person_name, weekday & bits.BitMask single_weekday
  from person_days 
       inner join bits on person_days.weekday & bits.BitMask > 0
)
select person_name, sum(single_weekday) weekdays
  from person_single_days
 group by person_name;
```

result:

```
person_name weekdays
----------- -----------
Jane        41
John        11
```

Comment: You simulate a OR by doing a sum of AND's, that's because you don't have a means to do a OR aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

"inspired" by Roman's CTE: (note that the first CTE just generates demo data)

```
with p as 
(
    select 'John' as PERSON_NAME, 1 as PERSON_DAY
    union
    select 'John', 3 
    union
    select 'John', 8
    union
    select 'Jane', 2
    union
    select 'Jane', 4
),
cte as
(
    select PERSON_NAME, PERSON_DAY from p
    union all
    select cte2.PERSON_NAME, p.PERSON_DAY | cte2.PERSON_DAY 
        from p 
        inner join cte as cte2 on p.PERSON_NAME = cte2.PERSON_NAME 
        where p.PERSON_DAY & cte2.PERSON_DAY = 0
)   
select PERSON_NAME, MAX(PERSON_DAY) from cte
group by PERSON_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a custom aggregate that does an OR. You can write that using SQL CLR in .NET. This is probably the cleanest solution. It will be reusable, too.

Alternatively, you could use cursor-based loops to calculate the result.

You could also (mis)use CTE's for this purpose.